# spring java config not present in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

Following is my spring java config. I am not referencing ApplicationContext.java anywhere in my web.xml. Yet, methods in following bean are called and my application context is being initialized successfully. How is that possible?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@PropertySource({ "file:/etc/XXX/core/database.properties", "file:/etc/XXX/core/mail.properties" })
public class ApplicationContext {

    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String databasePassword;

    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${database.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;

    @Value("${database.driverClassName}")
    private String databaseDriverClassName;

...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's component scanning captures classes annotated with `@Configuration`.

Without seeing the rest of your config I can't tell you specifically where you're telling Spring to component scan, but that's what's going on.

Comment: makes sense. I have another applicationcontext.xml that has <component-scan> enabled.  and that xml is being referenced.